# Open Port Issue on CentOS

Tags: centos

I'm working on a CentOS 6 machine. I've tried to follow the following guides:

- [How to open port in centOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034542/how-to-open-port-in-centos)
- http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html

If I run `nmap ipofmachine` on the target machine I have this strange result.

```
Host is up (0.0079s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

Still, when I run `sudo iptables -L` I have the following output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:webcache 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Am I missing something? Let me know if you need more information (I'm trying to open port 8080).

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow connections on a specific port you must configure the CentoOS firewall:

```
> sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
> sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

- *You need to configure privilege elevation with sudo*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IPTables, add the following rule into etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Then run the following command to save: iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables